# what is the flow of this code snippet?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

```js
function makeAdjectifier(adjective) {
    return function(string) {
        return adjective + "" + string;
    };
}
var coolifier = makeAdjectifier("COOL");
console.log(coolifier("conference")); //outputs "COOLconference"
```

So, what I see here is coolifier function is being called and conference string is passed as an argument, and coolifier which taking input from makeAdjectifier, & cool is passed as an argument so adjective becomes cool. Now again adjectifier is returning a function which is taking string as a parameter. how conference is available at the inner function so that string becomes equal to conference.

Comment: How? The returned function takes one parameter that you are passing in as string *"conference"*

Comment: no.. I think that is a different topic where you are referring. It is currying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That technique is called "currying" and the most basic explanation would be that by the time you invoked "makeAdjectifier", you created a function that is not only expecting a string but also is aware of the variables that were assigned during its creation.

Here's a cool reference: https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/